# How can I make a php code pop up a new window?

Tags: php, html, plugins, hyperlink, new-window

I have a wordpress plugin that allows me to send people to a new url. instead of it going to that URL on that same page and making users leave my website. I want a new window to open when they go to the url

How can I edit this code so that a new window opens ?

```
  <?php
    /**
  Plugin Name: [WPJB] Application URL
   Version: 1.1
  Author: Greg Winiarski
 Description: Allows to set application URL on per job basis.
*/

// Plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpjb_aurl_register');

function wpjb_aurl_register() {
// registers new custom field in wp_wpjb_meta table
wpjb_meta_register("job", "application_url");
}

// Plugin deactivation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpjb_aurl_unregister');

function wpjb_aurl_unregister() {
// do nothing ...
}

// Adding custom fields to the form
add_filter("wpjb_form_init_job", "wpjb_aurl_init_job");
add_filter("wpja_form_init_job", "wpjb_aurl_init_job");

function wpjb_aurl_init_job($form) {

// adding new fields to the form
$e = $form->create("application_url", "text");
$e->setBuiltin(false);
$e->setLabel("Application URL");
$e->addFilter(new Daq_Filter_WP_Url);
$e->addValidator(new Daq_Validate_Url);
$e->setValue($form->getObject()->meta->application_url->value());
$form->addElement($e, "company");

return $form;
}


add_action("wpjb_front_pre_render", "wpjb_aurl_pre_render", 10, 2);

 function wpjb_aurl_pre_render($app, $file) {
 global $post_type;

try {
    $c1 = is_wpjb() && wpjb_is_routed_to("index.single");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $c1 = false;
}
$c2 = $post_type == "job";

if(!$c1 && !$c2) {
    return;
}

$job = $app->controller->view->job;

if(!$job->meta->application_url->value()) {
    return;
}

$app->controller->view->application_url = $job->meta->application_url-    >value();

}

?>
```

Comment: windows are controlled on the client (browser) ... PHP runs on the server, so the short answer is that you can't do this purely in PHP

Comment: PHP is a server side language, you do not have control over the client's windows. You can however add `target='_new'` to links, so if someone clicks on them, they will be opened in a new window. Additionally, you could use jquery and open the window when the page loads.

Comment: its a job board , so when I create new jobs it automatically creates pages .. when someone views the job it has the option to apply , and when they click on apply it takes them to the url for that job.... idk how i could make this happen ?

Comment: This guide to links might help: [W3 schools targets](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp). It's like Jan said, you can add `target='_blank' to the links that you create to make that link open in a new tab.

Comment: wow...its not possible to do this or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it purely with `PHP`, but you can instead of redirecting to the new url echo javascript that will be fired on loading the page that will open the url in a new window or tab.

Using something like

```
Echo "<script> var win = window.open(".$job->meta->application_url->value().", '_blank'); win.focus();</script>";
```

In your php script probably on the position you have now

```
$app->controller->view->application_url = $job->meta->application_url->value();
```

Comment: So exactly in this php code iv provided above, enter it where?

Comment: Changed my answer, since I am not familiar with the plugin it is a guess where to place it.

Comment: No you put it instead of the line I say last.